How to deploy a react-redux-vite app that has Express backend to Netlify
I am working on an app that is built with React, Redux, Vite in the frontend and Express in the backend. The frontend makes requests to the backend for fetching an access token, user-details and data from the reddit API. Currently, I try to deploy it with Netlify with serverless functions, but no matter what I try, I can't make it work. What can I do next?
My folder structure is as follows:
root-folder/
├── .netlify
├── client/
│   ├── .netlify/
│   ├── coverage/
│   ├── dist/
│   ├── node_modules/
│   ├── public/
│   ├── server/
│   │   └── functions/
│   ├── src/
│   │   ├── file1.ext
│   │   └── file2.ext
│   ├── .eslintrc.js
│   ├── .gitignore
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   └── vite.config.js
├── node_modules
├── server/
│   │   ├── netlify/ 
│   │   │   └── functions/ 
│   │   │       └── api.js
│   │   ├── routes/
│   │   ├── auth.js
│   │   ├── logout.js
│   │   ├── token.js
│   │   └── refreshToken.js
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   └── package.json
├── .gitignore
├── netlify.toml
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── README.md

So, whilst I wrote my folder structure, I encountered that Netlify must have created a server-folder into the client-folder. Until now, I tried to implement everything in the server-folder that I used for the local deployment. Was this wrong? Do I have to bring everything into the client-folder?
My server/functions/api.js look like this:
import express, { Router } from "express";
import serverless from "serverless-http";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";

dotenv.config();

const api = express();

const origin = ['my.netlify.app']

const corsOptions = {
  origin: origin,
  methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
  allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],

};

console.log(corsOptions)

api.use(cors(corsOptions)); // Use CORS middleware
api.use(express.json()); // Parse JSON bodies

const authRoute = require("../../routes/Auth");
const tokenRoute = require("../../routes/Token");
const logoutRoute = require("../../routes/Logout");
const refreshTokenRoute = require("../../routes/RefreshToken");

api.use("/auth", authRoute);
api.use("/token", tokenRoute);
api.use("/refreshToken", refreshTokenRoute);
api.use("/logout", logoutRoute);

// Test route
const router = Router();
router.get("/hello", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World!"));
api.use("/api/", router);

// Export the handler for Netlify
export const handler = serverless(api);

My netlify.toml is:
[functions]
  directory = "server/netlify/functions" 
  external_node_modules = ["express", "dotenv"]
  node_bundler = "esbuild"
[build]
  base = "client"                
  publish = "dist"                
  command = "npm run build"      
[[redirects]]
  force = true
  from = "/api/*"
  status = 200
  to = "server/netlify/functions"

And my vite.config.js:
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: '/',
  plugins: [
    react(),
  ],
  test: {
    environment: 'jsdom', 
    globals: true, 
    setupFiles: './src/__tests__/setup.js',// inclides the setup testfile 
  }
});


What things are you seeing in Netlify when you deploy or access the site? Are there any logs you're seeing?
